# Sencha touch - Facebook style sliding menu - is it possible?

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch

There are a couple of plugins that appear to say it is so we've had a bash at writing our own. We can get it to work beautifully in the browser but when we try to deploy to device it goes horribly wrong - overlaying the components in a visual mess. Anyone have any thoughts on this?

```
Ext.Viewport.add( Ext.create('WC.view.Wrapper') )

where then the wrapper is a List (Menu) and a Main(Main)

Ext.define('WC.view.Wrapper', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'ObjectTabContainer',

    requires: [
        'WC.view.layout.RecordList',          // Menu
        'WC.view.layout.RightContainer'     // Main
    ],

    config: {

        items: [

            // Hidden appers to display no connection
            {
                xtype  : 'ConnectionStatusIndicator',
                docked : 'top'
            },
            // WC.view.layout.RecordList > list
            {
                xtype: 'RecordList',
                id   : 'recordlist'
            },
            // WC.view.layout.RightContainer > toolbars and data
            {
                xtype: 'RightContainer',
                id   : 'rightcontainer'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

in terms of z-index I have

```
List > style : 'position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2, height:
100%'
RightContainer > style  : 'width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;
top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 3; opacity: 1'
```

Problem is that on the device I see the two components slightly overlapped
(not completely top to bottom... ) + when I click the button nothing
happens... I have tried to debug as much as possible using alerts and what
happens is that the code stops here, without any type of errors...

```
Ext.define('WC.controller.SlideCtrl', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Require elements for this class (otherwise require them at app.js
level)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    requires: [
    'WC.view.layout.RecordList',
        'WC.view.layout.RightContainer'
    ],

    config: {
    refs: {
    RecordList    : 'RecordList',
            RightContainer: 'RightContainer',
            menuButton    : 'RightContainer RecordInterationToolbar
button[action=openMenu]'
    },

    control: {
            menuButton: {
    tap: 'onOpenMenuButtonTapped'
    },

     .......
     ........

onOpenMenuButtonTapped: function(){
        alert('0')
        var main = this.getRightContainer();
        var menu = this.getRecordList();
        alert('1') ====================>>>>>> here stops > doesn't even
enters the main.isClosed()
        alert(main.isClosed())
        if (main.isClosed()) {
            alert('call open menu')
            main.openMenu(menu.getOpenAnimDuration());
            alert('after call open menu')
        } else {
            alert('call open close menu')
            main.closeMenu(menu.getCloseAnimDuration());
            alert('after call open close menu')
        }
        alert('end of onOpenMenuButtonTapped')
    }

=========> I should at least get the alert('isClosed')

isClosed: function() {
        alert('isClosed')
        alert(this.getDraggable().offset.x)
        alert('return')
        return (this.getDraggable().offset.x == 0);
    }
```

And keep in mind that in the browser it looks ok + the controller does its
dirty job!!! Plus the component by itself works perfectly on my device (I
mean same z-index and controller functions)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this plugin :

https://github.com/wnielson/sencha-SlideNavigation

in browser and in compiled app without issues, give it a try.

Comment: Can you give instruction on how you got this extension working. I'm trying to install it but I've been unsuccessful